# how does this if-statement work? (shell scripting )

Tags: shell, ubuntu, unix

```
if $* >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo Command \""$*"\" succeeded
else
        echo Command \""$*"\" failed
fi
```

as far as I understand it:
The passed parameters are output in the "black hole".
Then the stderr is redirected to the stdout.
But why does this cause the condition to be met when a passed command is issued successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the `if $* >/dev/null 2>&1; then` command:

- The general syntax is `if COMMANDS; then`. In you case `COMMANDS` is just a single command `$* >/dev/null 2>&1`.
- This command redirects the output to the null device (`>/dev/null`) and redirects the error output to the standard output (`2>&1`) and therefore also to the null device.
- The command itself is retrieved by expanding `$*`. This special variable expands to the arguments of the shell script.

So in essence: The command and its argument is expanded from `$*` and the output as well as the error output redirected to the null device.

Comment: but if the output and the error output are redirected to the null device, there should be no output, right?
And why can the script detect if a command was executed successfully?

Comment: Yes, there is no output. But the success of a command doesn't depend on the output. Whether a command was successful or not depends on its *exit status*. This is an integer value stored in the process information table of the kernel. If the exit status is 0, the command was executed successfully. Any other value implies that the command was not successful.

Comment: yes that is my problem 0 always means false but does the shell recognize that this zero comes from a command that was successfully executed and interprets it as true?

Comment: Why do you think that 0 means false? If you are coming from a C background then yes, in C 0 equals false. But that is not a general truth, e.g. in Ruby 0 is just like any other integer and is a truthy value. With regards to exit status codes, 0 means success and any other number means false. This is just how it is defined.